# Site is not loading properly in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.2

I am using Magento 1.9.2, Some times site is not loading properly like no CSS and JS file loading. And once I delete cache files manually it works fine, It is happening quite regularly. Any specific reason for this issue.

Comment: Are you using any cdn??

Comment: i'd assume you are running out of disk quota on that account if you are on a shared hosting > flushing cache files frees disk space. Also look for information on the var/log/system.log or var/log/exception.log also on the php error logs and/or apache/nginx logs